# On click show next tab in formular (div)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got multiple divs with the class tab `<div class="tab">i am div 1</div><div class="tab">i am div 2 </div>`. Inside i have some input field anon the bottom I got a next and back button

```
    <div class="funnel-buttons text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="icon-btn" id="prevBtn">Back</button>
                        <button type="button" class="icon-btn" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextTab()">Next</button>
    </div>
```

now after clicking next or back button I want the next or prev div to shown up so I made a JS function when tab[0] is displayed and clicking next I should dissappear.

```
const tab = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextBtn');
tab[0].style.display = 'block';
tab[1].style.display = 'none';

function nextTab () {
    if(tab[0].style.display == 'block') {
        tab[1].style.display = 'block';
        tab[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

But when I do so all the tabs disappear and nothing is shown.
Where is the error?

Comment: you can try visibility 'hidden'  instead of 'noe'

Comment: no, its also not working :(

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a variable to capture which is the current tab - in my code `currentVisible`. Based on that you can manipulate which tab you want to see on the UI. Also you can use `.forEach()` to iterate through all the `<div>` elements which has `tab` class added. Finally you can change the visibility with [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like `i === currentVisible ? 'block' : 'none'`.

Try as the following:

```js
const tab = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextBtn');
let currentVisible = 0;

const handleTab = n => {
  if (currentVisible + n >= 0 && currentVisible + n < tab.length) {
    currentVisible += n;
    
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(tab, (e, i) => {
      tab[i].style.display = i === currentVisible ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
  }
}

handleTab(0);
```

```html
<div class="funnel-buttons text-right">
  <button type="button" class="icon-btn" id="prevBtn" onclick="handleTab(-1)">Back</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon-btn" id="nextBtn" onclick="handleTab(1)">Next</button>
</div>

<div class="tab">I am div 1</div>
<div class="tab">I am div 2 </div>
<div class="tab">I am div 3</div>
<div class="tab">I am div 4 </div>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

you can solve like this

```js
const tab = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextBtn');




function nextTab() {
  const currentTab = document.querySelector('.show');
  const tabArray = Array.from(tab);
  const currentIndex = tabArray.indexOf(currentTab);
  console.log(currentIndex);
  currentTab.classList.remove('show');
  currentTab.classList.add('hide');
  if (tabArray.length > currentIndex + 1) {
    tabArray[currentIndex + 1].classList.remove('hide');
    tabArray[currentIndex + 1].classList.add('show');
  } else {
  // to return first tab at the end
    tabArray[0].classList.remove('hide');
    tabArray[0].classList.add('show');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .show {
      display: block;
    }

    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tab show">1</div>
  <div class="tab hide">2</div>
  <div class="tab hide">3</div>

  <div class="funnel-buttons text-right">
    <button type="button" class="icon-btn" id="prevBtn">Back</button>
    <button type="button" class="icon-btn" id="nextBtn"
      onclick="nextTab()">Next</button>
  </div>


  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Dariun if this answer is work for you, please mark as correct( click tick) for future readings.